# How to get every possible combination of 8 characters?

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to save every combination of AAAAAAAA - ZZZZZZZZ to a text file. So far after having many many errors, I have got almost nowhere. I could post my code if needed, but it doesn't work or get near the wanted outcome.

So I was wondering how to do this in c#. My method at the moment is beyond repair, I will have to start all again in order to fix this.

As the output I would like something along the lines of

> AAAAAAAA, AAAAAAAB, AAAAAAAC ... ZZZZZZZX, ZZZZZZZY, ZZZZZZZZ

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6):

This is a basic combinatorics question:
You want to write a string of 8 characters.
Each character can be a letter between A-Z (26 options), therefore, there are `26^8` combinations: `26*26*26*...26`.
That is `208827064576` combinations.
Each combination is `10 bytes` (8 for string, then \r\n), which is a total of `1944.85 GB`.
Are you sure you want to write it to a file?

Answer (score 3):

This will take about 1.5-2 Terabytes. That's a huge text file to start with, probably impractical.

Secondly, the way to do this simply is to have 8 nested loops, each running through A to Z, then concatenate the string inside the inner loop, appending to the data store each time.

Comment: I need to write it to a file, as it needs to be read by another program. The size is a small problem as I only need it for 2-3 days. I have enough free space until then. Size aside, thanks for this answer, while this isn't the method I used (the one in the comment section of OP) this is how I originally intended to do this, after reading your question I realised my mistake and fixed it.

Comment: Why does it need to be read by another program? Why can't you adjust the other program to simply generate the string on the fly from the (base 26) number?

Comment: unfortunately the other program is not written by me, and is also not open source. There are alternatives, but none are as powerful as the one I wish to use. The way I decided to do was make a 40GB chunk of each block, use that, then delete the file and generate the next chunk, rinse and repeat until I have ran all possibilities.

Comment: I'm curious what your program's intended use/purpose is?